# Mean from ggplot stat_summary is different to calculated mean

Tags: r

I have a dataset between 0 and 1 that includes about 20% 0s. I have noticed that the mean calculated by `stat_summary` from `ggplot` is different to the calculated by hand. Why?

```
set.seed(190)

b<-runif(1000)*1e-6

#Create 0s
b[sample(NROW(b),200)]<-0

#Plot it and create a x for the mean.
tibble(value=b, name=rep(1,1e3)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=b))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_y_log10()+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=4, size=3, color="black") ->a
  ggplotly(a)
```

[image]
Calculating this mean by hand:

```
tibble(value=b, name=rep(1,1e3))  %>% 
  summarise(mean(b))

4.068419e-07
```

Comment: I think you have a seed problem. For me, `mean(b)` is `4.02136e-07`, and the displayed log10-mean is `6.433` (which is `mean(log10(b[b>0]))`). The warnings from `ggplot2` about `Removed 200 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot)` are likely a hint that your 200 `0`s are being removed.

Comment: I understand what you mean (pun not intended) so realistically, the median may be a more meaningful statistic. But those don't match either: from graph=-6.31, by hand= -6.412. What do you think?

Comment: `median(log10(b[b>0]))` is `6.306`, so it does match. `ggplot2` is removing the `-Inf` (on the log scale) and then calculating the mean/median.

Comment: I don't know which is better (mean vs median) for your use, but the issue is that the mean/median is not on the whole set. Perhaps you instead want to display a point at `log10(mean(b))` or `log10(median(b))`? Those are very different numbers.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense about the removed values (I didn't have the console open so didn't see that warning). Hmm I'll have to think about what is actually meaningful in this case.

Comment: Funny ... I can't imagine not having the R console front-and-center, so I hadn't considered that you had not seen those warnings :-)

Comment: Yeah, I was using an Rmarkdown document and had zoomed into the source. This has actually opened another can of worms because I'm trying to recreate some python plots and those may treat 0s differently. I can recreate the mean values they have but not the plots. :-)

Comment: I've discovered `scales::pseudo_log_trans()`that substitutes all the `-inf` values associated with log(0) with 0s. I'm not sure that convinces me either but at least it keeps all the values in the plot